# Cat all files in a folder including filename by using a for loop?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cat

With this for loop which I execute directly in the shell, I am able to cat the contents of all files in a folder, with the value beside of it:

```
$ for f in *; do echo -e "\t"$f"\n"; cat $f; done
```

Example output:

```
100 
    testfile1
    testfile3      <-No output because this file is empty
hello 
    testfile2
```

But I'd like to print the value on the right side and the file on the top left like this:

```
testfile1 
    100
testfile3
testfile2
    hello
```

I tried to swap the position of echo and cat but that doesn't work, it works exactly as the other command.

```
$ for f in *; cat $f; do echo -e "\t"$f"\n"; done
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your example output does not match your first command line, but the second one.

Answer (score 9):

```
for f in *; do
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
  paste /dev/null - < "$f"
done
```

Would print the file name followed by its content with each line preceded by a TAB character for each file in the directory.

Same with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME};{print "\t" $0}' ./*
```

Or to avoid printing the name of empty files (this one not GNU specific):

```
awk 'FNR==1 {print FILENAME}; {print "\t" $0}' ./*
```

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -s '1F;s/^/\t/' ./*
```

Comment: I tried to execute the first command in the terminal, but it does not work

Comment: @EdwardBlack "Does not work" is not a very helpful comment. Did you get an error message? Did you get the wrong output? I tried all four variants here and they all work for me.

Comment: I just get a ">" prompt where i have to enter something, the command is not complete as it seems

Comment: Entered one line at a time? The > is a secondary shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *; do echo -e "$(cat $f)\t"$f; done
```

Answer (score -1):

I found a possible solution:

```
for f in *; do echo -e $f"\n\t$(cat $f)"; done
```